# Extracting differences between consecutive lines in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to loop trough n lines of a file and for any `i` between `1` and `n-1` to get the difference between words of `line(n-1) - line(n)` (eg. `line[i]word[j] - line[i+1]word[j]` etc .. )

**Input :**

```
Hey there !
Hey thre !
What a suprise.
What a uprise.
I don't know what to do.
I don't know wt to do.
```

**Output:**

```
e
s
ha
```

The goal is to extract the missing character(s) between two consecutive line words only.

I'm new to python so if you can guide me through writing the code, I would be more than thankful.

Comment: read this perhaps: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff

Comment: @DirtyBit instead, please read https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff let's not use references to python2 wherever possible

Comment: Use difflib as described in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775029/finding-differences-between-strings

Comment: I am not sure but the reason of the downvote may be because it sounds like a homework assignment. If that is the case know that answering homework questions isn't the purpose of Stack overflow.

Comment: it's not a homework , it's part of a bigger pipeline i'm working on, and i'm stuck with this part that I decided to do using python.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek while it is unlikely for homework questions to be a good question, it isn't explicitly disallowed.  All the community asks in return is that the asker has already exhausted all avenues of research (unlikely) and made attempts at solving themselves (usually are rather half baked attempts though).  There was a FAQ on asking homework questions but I don't have the reference handy.

Comment: Fair enough. Welcome to SO by the way !

Answer (score -1):

Without any lib :

```py
def extract_missing_chars(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        return extract_missing_chars(s2, s1)
    i = 0
    to_return = []
    for c in s1:
        if s2[i] != c:
            to_return.append(c)
        else:
            i += 1
    return to_return

f = open('testfile')
l1 = f.readline()
while l1:
    l2 = f.readline()
    print(''.join(extract_missing_chars(l1, l2)))
    l1 = f.readline()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example indicates that you want the comparisons between pairs of lines.  This is different from defining it as line(n-1)-line(n) which would give you 5 results, not 3.

The result also depends on what you consider to be differences.  Is it positional, is it simply based on missing letters from the odd lines or are the differences applicable in both directions.
(e.g. "boat"-"tub" = "boat", "oa"  or "oau" ?).
You also have to decide if you want the differences to be case sensitive or not.

Here's an example where computation of the differences is centralized in a function so that you can change the rules more easily.  It assumes that "boat"-"tub" = "oau".

```
lines = """Hey there !
Hey thre !
What a suprise.
What a uprise.
I don't know what to do.
I don't know wt to do.
""".split('\n')

def differences(word1,word2):
    if isinstance(word1,list):
        return "".join( differences(w1,w2) for w1,w2 in zip(word1+[""]*len(word2),word2+[""]*len(word1)) )
    return "".join( c*abs(word1.count(c)-word2.count(c)) for c in set(word1+word2) )

result = [ differences(line1.split(),line2.split()) for line1,line2 in zip(lines[::2],lines[1::2]) ]

# ['e', 's', 'ha']
```

*Note that line processing for `result` is based on your example (not on your definition).*